# Why the variables are not updating? Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am struck on here, the errors as pic1 shows, and 2.3 are the coding that I wrote.
I use the same coding in another simulation and it works, I don't know what's happened in this new model.

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zkm83.png)   [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x2jh.png)     [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQqyz.png)

Comment: this questions is impossible to understand... what is the error that you get?

Comment: It doesn't show the error pic, I will upload again

Comment: Even with this, it is impossible to really answer. You have a different model with a different structure now, apparently. Some of those "A", "countB" etc are not where the code expects them to be... Best understand your model hierarchy and check the help on OOP: https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately from what you show, it's impossible to know what your variable "agent" represents.

Nevertheless it can be said that it doesn't represent what you think, since your errors indicate that agent doesn't have any parameter or variable that you define there.

If you are using that code in a block, make sure that an agent of the type you want is flowing through that block.

If you are using a function, make sure that "agent" represents the type you want it to represent.

The most likely thing you are doing wrong is that you haven't define what kind of agent is flowing through your process modeling flowchart